# Product of two number using javascript

Tags: javascript

I using javascript to  determine the product of two numbers but I am not able to get the output on 
`**<input type="number" id="custom-message" name="frames"></textarea>**.` Please help me find my mistake.

```js
function calculate() {
   var myBox1 = document.getElementsByName("height")[0].value; 
  var myBox2 = document.getElementsByName("width")[0].value;
  var frames = document.getElementsByName('frames'); 
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  frames.value = myResult;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="custom-message" name="height" oninput="calculate()"></textarea>
    <input type="number" id="custom-message" name="width" oninput="calculate()"></textarea>
    <input type="number" id="custom-message" name="frames"></textarea>
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a **list** of elements. Which, you seem to know because you are accessing the first element of those lists in `getElementsByName("height")[0]` and `getElementsByName("width")[0]`. Now you need to do the same for `getElementsByName('frames')`.

Comment: Are those elements `<input>`s or `<textarea>`s? Also don't give them the same id.

Comment: Why you have closed input tag with textarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove `</textarea>` tag

```js
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementsByName("height")[0].value; 
  var myBox2 = document.getElementsByName("width")[0].value;
  var frames = document.getElementsByName('frames')[0]; 
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  frames.value = myResult;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="custom-message" name="height" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="number" id="custom-message" name="width" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="number" id="custom-message" name="frames">
```

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you pointed out the part of your code that fixes the problem, specifically using the first element from the list of elements returned by `getElementsByName('frames')`.

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked your code mainly using what people have put into the comments and general coding best practices.

- Changed your input elements to be self-closing instead of closing them with textarea tags. I don't know where you learned to do that, but unlearn it now.
- Don't give multiple elements the same ID. It is also much easier to reference elements by ID than by name, so I changed the names to be IDs
- Made the frames into a paragraph instead of an input, because you don't want  people to try and input something there. If you have to have it be an input, disable it and style it appropriately with CSS.
- Added error checking so there is no calculation unless both values are positive numbers.
- I made your variables global variables because I like doing things that way and my OCD goes crazy if I don't, but the way you had it was okay too.

```js
var myBox1 = document.getElementById("height");
var myBox2 = document.getElementById("width");
var frames = document.getElementById("frames"); 
function calculate() {
  if (Number(myBox1.value) > 0 && Number(myBox2.value) > 0) {
   var myResult = myBox1.value * myBox2.value;
   frames.innerHTML = myResult;
  } else {
    frames.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```css
#frames {
  font-size: 2em
}
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="height" id="height" name="height" oninput="calculate()" />
<input type="number" placeholder="width" id="width" name="width" oninput="calculate()" />
<p id="frames"></p>
```

Comment: i am using get document.ElementsByName